# Read pcap header length field with python

Tags: python, pcap

I have captured some packets using pcap library in c. Now i am using python program to read that saved packet file. but i have a problem here. I have a file which first have pkthdr(provided by lybrary) and then actual packet.
format of pkthdr is-

```
struct pcap_pkthdr {
    struct timeval ts; /* time stamp 32bit */ 32bit
    bpf_u_int32 caplen; /* length of portion present */
    bpf_u_int32 len; /* length this packet (off wire) */
};
```

now i want to read len field, so i have skipped timeval and cap len, and printed len field using python in binary form.. the binary code which i got is-
01001010 00000000 00000000 00000000
Now how to read it in u_int32, i dont think it is correct value(too large), actual len field value should be  74 byte(check in wireshark).. so please tell me what i am doing wrong.. 
thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your python code?

Answer (score 1):

Or have a look at the [pylibpcap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pylibpcap/) module, the [pypcap](http://code.google.com/p/pypcap/) module, or the [pcapy](http://www.darknet.org.uk/2007/12/pcapy-python-interface-to-libpcap/) module, which let you just call pcap APIs with relative ease.  That way you don't have to *care* about the details of pcap files, and your code will, with libpcap 1.1 or later, also be able to read at least some of the pcap-ng files that Wireshark can produce and that it will produce *by default* in the 1.8 release.

Writing your own code to read pcap files, rather than relying on libpcap/WinPcap to do so, is rarely worth doing.  (Wireshark does so, as part of its library that reads a number of capture file formats and supports pcap-ng format in ways that the current pcap API can't, but the library in question also supports pcap-ng....)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`struct` module](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html), which lets you unpack such binary data with relative ease, for example:

```
struct.unpack('LLL', yourbuffer)
```

This will give you a tuple of the three (L = unsigned long) values. If the len value doesn't seem right, the [byte order](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) of the file is different from your native one. In that case prefix the format string with either `>` (big-endian) or `<` (little-endian):

```
struct.unpack('>LLL', yourbuffer)
```